# rendering a dynamic form in a MERN stack app

Tags: react-hooks, material-ui, mern

I am trying to render a dynamic form - instead of having 10 input fields, I would like to have 2 or 3 as default, and the user when clicks add icon will render an extra input field. My problem is that when I do that how do I keep track of the ingredient number and put a stop when it reaches ingredient10. Note: I do not have the add icon added into my code base, but I will add it as a button icon with an onClick function

```js
const [addCocktail, setAddCocktail] = useState({
    title: "",
    type_of_drink: "",
    glass: "",
    tags: "",
    ingredient1: "",
    ingredient2: "",
    ingredient3: "",
    ingredient4: "",
    ingredient5: "",
    ingredient6: "",
    ingredient7: "",
    ingredient8: "",
    ingredient9: "",
    ingredient10: "",
    preparation: "",
    selectedFiles: "",
  });

        <TextField
          name="ingredient1"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Ingredient"
          fullWidth
          value={addCocktail.ingredient1}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setAddCocktail({ ...addCocktail, ingredient1: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="ingredient2"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Ingredient"
          fullWidth
          value={addCocktail.ingredient2}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setAddCocktail({ ...addCocktail, ingredient2: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="ingredient3"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Ingredient"
          fullWidth
          value={addCocktail.ingredient3}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setAddCocktail({ ...addCocktail, ingredient3: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="ingredient4"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Ingredient"
          fullWidth
          value={addCocktail.ingredient4}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setAddCocktail({ ...addCocktail, ingredient4: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="ingredient5"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Ingredient"
          fullWidth
          value={addCocktail.ingredient5}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setAddCocktail({ ...addCocktail, ingredient5: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="ingredient6"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Ingredient"
          fullWidth
          value={addCocktail.ingredient6}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setAddCocktail({ ...addCocktail, ingredient6: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="ingredient7"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Ingredient"
          fullWidth
          value={addCocktail.ingredient7}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setAddCocktail({ ...addCocktail, ingredient7: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="ingredient8"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Ingredient"
          fullWidth
          value={addCocktail.ingredient8}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setAddCocktail({ ...addCocktail, ingredient8: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="ingredient9"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Ingredient"
          fullWidth
          value={addCocktail.ingredient9}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setAddCocktail({ ...addCocktail, ingredient9: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <TextField
          name="ingredient10"
          variant="outlined"
          label="Ingredient"
          fullWidth
          value={addCocktail.ingredient10}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setAddCocktail({ ...addCocktail, ingredient10: e.target.value })
          }
        />
```

Comment: Have a look at `react-hook-form` library

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generating fields can be done relatively simply with state.

I [made a quick example](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-dynamic-text-fields-with-button-k7hse?file=/index.js) where you get 3 default fields and can add fields with a button up to a max of 10.  Please forgive the lack of styling.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Add } from "@material-ui/icons";

const maxInputFields = 10;
const defaultNumberOfFields = 3;

function App() {
  const [numberOfFields, setNumberOfFields] = useState(defaultNumberOfFields);

  function generateInputField(ingredientNum) {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField variant="outlined" label={`Ingredient ${ingredientNum}`} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  function generateFields() {
    let listOfFields = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfFields; i++) {
      listOfFields.push(generateInputField(i));
    }
    return listOfFields;
  }

  function handleButtonClick() {
    if (numberOfFields < maxInputFields) setNumberOfFields(numberOfFields + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {generateFields()}
      {numberOfFields < maxInputFields && (
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={handleButtonClick}
        >
          <Add />
        </Button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```